# How can I make my Widget gradient with transparency?

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile, widget, appbar

I've got my own widget over here. I use it as my Appbar. I want it to be gradient with opacity but it doesn't work. Actually I thought that when I place the BoxDecoration into that first Container it will work. I am pretty new to flutter. Any advice? The first part is my widget. The second ist my Home class where I set it as my appbar.

```
Widget customAppBar(double width) {
return PreferredSize(
preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(124),
child: Container(
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    gradient: LinearGradient(
      begin: Alignment.topCenter,
      end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
      colors: [
        Color(0xff101010).withOpacity(1),
        Color(0xff101010).withOpacity(0.82),
        Color(0xff101010).withOpacity(0)
      ],
    ),
  ),
  width: width,
  // height: 124,
  child: Row(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
    children: <Widget>[
      Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 30, top: 44, bottom: 13),
        width: 134,
        height: 39,
        child: FlatButton(
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
          ),
          color: Color(0xffff163c),
          child: Text(
            "LOCKDOWN",
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.white,
              fontSize: 18,
              fontFamily: 'Assistant',
            ),
          ),
          onPressed: () {},
        ),
      ),
      Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20, right: 12, left: 48),
        height: 76,
        width: 152,
        child: Image.asset(
          'assets/images/xy.png',
          fit: BoxFit.none,
        ),
      )
    ],
  ),
),
```

);
}

```
class Home extends StatefulWidget {
@override
_HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
MediaQueryData queryData = MediaQuery.of(context);
return Scaffold(
  // resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
  backgroundColor: Color(0xff101010),
  // extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,
  appBar: customAppBar(queryData.size.width),
  body: SingleChildScrollView(
    child: Body(),
  ),
);
```

}
}

Comment: Please, provide also where and how you call `customAppBar()` function

Comment: I copied your code and remove Image asset and pass to `customAppBar()` double.maxFinite variable - all works pretty good.

Comment: @Abjox I did it.

Comment: remove background color from Scaffold and you will see corret gradient

Comment: @Abjox but I want it to stay black. If I scroll up my body I want that the buttons in my body disappear slowly in the AppBar. you know what I mean?